# Regular expression for string in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

My string is : BETA-GE=a034-56aw-y567-54er; beta=/;

I would like to retrieve the string "a034-56aw-y567-54er" from the above string in nodejs.

The code I have written currently is:

```
var xs = "BETA-GE=a034-56aw-y567-54er; beta=/;";
var regex = /^BETA-GE=[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[;]*./;
let match = regex.exec(xs);
console.log(match[0]);
```

The result displays BETA-GE=a034-56aw-y567-54er;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surround the part you want with a [capture group](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups) and access it:

```
var xs = "BETA-GE=a034-56aw-y567-54er; beta=/;";
var regex = /^BETA-GE=([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)[;]*./;
let match = regex.exec(xs);
console.log(match[1]);
```

Here is the [working regex](https://regex101.com/r/qqCJRr/1).

Answer (score 0):

You have just to create a group in your regexp and get the second match :

```
var xs = "BETA-GE=a034-56aw-y567-54er; beta=/;";
var regex = /^BETA-GE=([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)[;]*./;
let match = regex.exec(xs);
console.log(match[1]);
```